# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field on serializer

Tags: django, serialization

I get the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
> `first_name` on serializer `AthleteSerializer`. The serializer field
> might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `QuerySet` instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object
> has no attribute 'first_name'.

Why do I get an error?

This is my `views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Athlete

from athletics.serializers import AthleteSerializer

class ListAthletes(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_athletes = Athlete.objects.all()
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        serializer = AthleteSerializer(all_athletes)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my `serializers.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Athlete

class AthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Athlete
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )
```

This is my `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

class Athlete(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this:

```
serializer = AthleteSerializer(all_athletes, many=True)
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking a follow up question. If I am looking to understand any particular Django function and the parameters that should be passed to it, what is a good place to find this? When I google I often end up on the djangoproject.com documentation, which to make seems pretty wordy and I have to read around before I understand which parameters can be passed.

Comment: @user1283776 , I often look at django documentation and stackoverflow questions.

Comment: If you're looking for DRF, then here is the best tool I use: http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.serializers/ModelSerializer.html

Answer (score 8):

[Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3465428/hasan-ramezani)  is right in [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33523941/11573842) `many=True`.

What it means in DRF is that since your `serializer.data` is going to be a list and each item in the list needs to be converted to python datatypes that further will be easily rendered into JSON, XML.

Do not be confused with the many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you get the "AttributeError" on serializer, always see the last part where it says 'the original exception was...'. This is why the actual error occurs. E.g

```
"Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on 
serializer `RegionSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named 
incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` 
instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 
'name'."
```

Here, as you can see, the end part which is "QuerySet" object has not attribute xyz .

Hope it is helpful